# test -r contradicts ls -l

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ls, test

I'm struggling with files and directory permissions.
`ls -l` is telling me something that `test -w` contradicts.

```
$ ls -l
total 1792
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data     168 Jan 29 23:53 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data   19421 Jan 29 23:53 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data   14547 Jan 29 23:53 CREDITS
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data      95 Jan 29 23:53 FAQ
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data 1414049 Jan 29 23:53 HISTORY
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    3638 Jan 29 23:53 INSTALL
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    5273 Jan 29 23:54 LocalSettings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    1530 Jan 29 23:53 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data   36717 Jan 29 23:53 RELEASE-NOTES-1.39
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data     199 Jan 29 23:53 SECURITY
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    4371 Jan 29 23:53 UPGRADE
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    4496 Jan 29 23:53 api.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data  156078 Jan 29 23:53 autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root www-data    4096 Jan 29 23:53 images
```

```
$ sudo -u www-data test -r INSTALL; echo "$?"
0
$ sudo -u www-data test -w INSTALL; echo "$?"
1
$ sudo -u www-data test -x INSTALL; echo "$?"
1
```

www-data is a member of www-data

```
$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

apache seems to agree with `ls` as it can't upload to `image/`
What am I missing ?

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic

Comment: I can't reproduce those results, I get return code 0 for `-w`. Also, I think you have a typo, because `ls -l` shows `images` but you say apache can't write to `image/`. Finally, if the real goal here is to allow apache to write to images, I think you just need `chmod g+w images`. At the moment, the www-data group (which is presumably what your apache service is configured to run as) has read but not write permissions to images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test -w` does work well (your title says `test -r` but the question is about `test -w`, so I assume it was a typo).

If you look at `man test` or `man [` you can see:

> -w FILE
>
> > ```
> >    FILE exists and the user has write access.
> > ```

<sup>Note that `test` evaluates that **The user has read access**</sup>

In your case with these permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    3638 Jan 29 23:53 INSTALL
```

The **root** user (first `r`), members of group **www-data** (second `r`) and everyone else (third `r`), so anyone as long as they also have access to the directory, have **read access**.

Nevertheless, the  **www-data** group does not have **write** nor **execution** permissions and for that reason when you evaluate permissions for the **www-data** user  you get `1` (or false):

```bash
sudo -u www-data test -w INSTALL; echo "$?"
1
sudo -u www-data test -x INSTALL; echo "$?"
1
```

About

> apache seems to agree with ls as it can't upload to image/

That's correct too, because the permissions for `images` directory have non-write access for members of the group **www-data** (use `sudo chmod g+w` to grant access to that group).

The user running the apache process would also need *search* access (`x`) to all the directories leading up to that directory.

Comment: +1.  In short, all of those files/dirs are group-readable but not group-writable.  The owner is root, so only root has write permissions. The images subdirectory should probably be made group-writable with `chmod 775`. or maybe `chmod 2775` to make it setgid as well as group-writable.  Any existing files in images/ should probably also be made group-writable.   NOTE: the other files, especially any .php files, and the top-level directory itself should **not** be writable by www-data, that would be a security risk just waiting to be exploited.

Comment: @cas good observation! That's a good comment which complements my answer in a good way, specially about security risks that might exist in case of permissions whose are not properly configured.